# Why when using contextmenustrip right click for the first second the menu is not in mouse position?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**In the constructor:**

```
ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
ToolStripMenuItem item1 = new ToolStripMenuItem();
item1.Name = "Open File Folder Location";
item1.Text = "Open File Folder Location";
item1.Click += contextMenuStrip1_ItemClick;
ToolStripMenuItem item2 = new ToolStripMenuItem();
item2.Name = "Launch File";
item2.Text = "Launch File";
item2.Click += contextMenuStrip2_ItemClick;
ToolStripMenuItem item3 = new ToolStripMenuItem();
item3.Name = "Copy File";
item3.Text = "Copy File";
item3.Click += contextMenuStrip3_ItemClick;
contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(item1);
contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(item2);
contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(item3);
```

Then i check that the `listView` is not empty only then show the menu:

```
private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
```

And the event when i make right click to show the menu:

```
private void Lvnf_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                var hitTestInfo = ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
                if (hitTestInfo.Item != null)
                {
                    var loc = e.Location;
                    loc.Offset(ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Location);

                    var items = ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.CheckedItems;
                    if (items.Count > 0)
                    {
                        contextMenuStrip1.Items[2].Enabled = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        contextMenuStrip1.Items[2].Enabled = false;
                    }
                    contextMenuStrip1.Show(this, loc);
                }
            }
        }
```

When i make mouse right click for a second or less the menu of the `contextmenustrip` is show on the top of the `form1` then it's showing on the listView where the mouse is on the select item.

But how can i make that it will show the menu only on the item ?

I dragged the contextMenuStrip1 in the designer from the `toolbox` and i see now that the `contextmenustrip` is also show as menu in the top left of the `form1`.

This is a screenshot showing the menu right after i make right click on the top left of the form:

[image: First]

And this is second later the menu is moving to where it should be on the first time:

[image: First1]

Answer (score 2):

The problem was this line:

```
contextMenuStrip1.Show(this, loc);
```

this prefer to form1 control and it should be the listView control instead:

```
contextMenuStrip1.Show(ListViewCostumControl.lvnf, loc);
```